# logic in pexpect

Tags: python, ssh, telnet, pexpect

Hi I am using pexpect in Python to read ssh device information.

```
expObject = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/ssh %s@%s' % (username, device))
expObject.sendline(password)
```

After giving the password  I have show some device information and in command prompt it will ask press any key to continue; Once I press any key the info disappears.

I use below logic to capture other data coming after giving command like `show version`

```
    expObject.expect(CLI_PROMPT)
    data = expObject.before
```

So how do I capture the data which is displayed after giving password and before pressing any key to comtinue using "expObject".

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I needed the handle the text output line by line. To get this to work, you have to be aware that pexpect configures regexp such that .* pattern includes linefeeds, so instead of .* you have to use [^\n]* . Something like this should work in your situation:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh command goes here')
child.expect('password prompt text\r\n')
child.sendline(password)
data = ""
while True:
    i = child.expect(['press any key to continue', '[^\n]*\r\n'])
    if i == 0:
        break
    data += child.before
print data
```

This should work with a command that outputs the following:

```
password propt text
<start of data captured> - 1st line
a second line
a third line
last line <end of data that will be captured>
press any key to continue
```

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=220139

Is an excellent guide for exactly what you want to do.  I suspect you do not actually need to use expect and can accomplish everything you want with just ssh command execution and ssh keys.  For example:

```
hostA:~ jdizzle$ ssh hostB hostname
hostB
```

Here is another tutorial on ssh keys: http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/